# xamarin form: iOS webview not showing website run using react or ant design pro

Tags: ios, reactjs, xamarin, webview

I have problem showing the website which build using React and Ant Design Pro ON iOS webview.

On android  webview i can enable all the setting e.g. webView.Settings.EnableJavascript and other setttings to show the React/Ant Design Pro demo pages. Otherwise the webview is blank.

On iOS, how do I show the page with react and ant design. At the moment, it still in blank.

Comment: If you're saying that javascript is disabled-  then you can't.  React is built on javascript.  If javascript is off, nothing will be displayed.  There is no fix to that.

Comment: not javascript. On android, javascript was enabled already but i have to enabled other things in order to have those webpages to load e.g. DomStorageEnabled. I wonder what do i need to enable on iOS side

Comment: Can you provide a simple website link which build using React and Ant Design Pro?

Comment: http://preview.pro.ant.design here is the link.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set the `HorizontalOptions` and `VerticalOptions` of `webView` to **FillAndExpand**.

I tried both in Xamarin.forms and Xamarin.iOS, it works.

**Xamarin.forms:**

```
<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <WebView Source="https://preview.pro.ant.design/user/login" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
</StackLayout>
```

**Xamarin.iOS:**

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
         base.ViewDidLoad ();
         // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

         UIWebView webView = new UIWebView(View.Bounds);
         View.AddSubview(webView);

         var url = "https://preview.pro.ant.design/user/login"; // NOTE: https secure request
         webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(url)));
    }
```